# Two questions invloving limits/sequences

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I have two homework questions. If I could get any information as to where to start, that would be great. I am so lost.

1. Let $a_n$ be a convergent sequence with $A = \lim_n a_n$. Suppose you have a one-to-one correspondence function of naturals, $f$. Define a new sequence $b_n$ = $a_{f(n)}$. I am pretty sure I need to prove it, but I don't know how to begin.
2. Let $a_n$ be a bounded sequence. Define two sequences: $a_n^+ = \sup\{a_k\mid k\ge n\}$. $a_n^- = \inf\{a_k\mid k\ge n\}$. Prove that both sequences converge and that $\lim_n a_n^+\ge \lim_n a_n^-$. Also prove that if $a_n$ is convergent, then $\lim_n a_n = \lim_n a_n^+ = \lim_n a_n^-$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINTS:

1. You didn’t say, but I assume that you’re to prove that $\lim_n b_n=A$. Let $\epsilon>0$; there is an $m_\epsilon\in\Bbb N$ such that $|a_n-A|<\epsilon$ whenever $n\ge m_\epsilon$. If $F$ is any finite subset of $\Bbb N$, there is an $m_F\in\Bbb N$ such that $f(n)\notin F$ whenever $n\ge m_F$. Take $F=\{n\in\omega:n<m_\epsilon\}$, and consider $|b_n-A|$ for $n\ge m_F$.
2. Show that if $n>m$, then $a_n^+\le a_m^+$ and $a_n^-\le a_m^-$, so that both of the new sequences are monotonic.

Comment: I could have sworn I said it, but you were right. Thanks!

Comment: @user1646600: You’re welcome!